# Safe division function using the anycompatible pseudo-type in Postgres 13, gotchas?

Tags: postgresql, divide-by-zero

I've been wanting to add a safe division function for some time to help out team members who don't spend as much time writing SQL queries. I've just noticed that PG 13 seems to add an `anycompatible` pseudo-type. I've tried it out, and this seems to work as hoped and expected. I've not used the pseudo-types before, and I'm wondering if I'm stepping into something with risks and restrictions I might not be anticipating. Does anyone have some caveats to offer?

The function code is listed below, along with a quick `select` to illustrate its behavior in a few situations.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tools.div_safe(
    numerator   anycompatible,
    denominator anycompatible)

RETURNS real

AS $BODY$

SELECT numerator/NULLIF(denominator,0)::real

$BODY$
  LANGUAGE sql;

COMMENT ON FUNCTION tools.div_safe (anycompatible, anycompatible) IS
'Pass in any two numbers that are, or can be converted to, numbers, and get a safe division real result.';

ALTER FUNCTION tools.div_safe (anycompatible, anycompatible)
    OWNER TO user_bender;
```

Sample select and output:

```
-- (real, int))
select '5.1/nullif(null,0)', 5.1/nullif(null,0)    as result union all 
select 'div_safe(5.1,0)', div_safe(5.1, 0)         as result union all

-- (0, 0)
select '0/nullif(0,0)', 5.1/nullif(null,0)         as result union all 
select 'div_safe(0, 0)', div_safe(0, 0)            as result union all

-- (int, int)
select '5/nullif(8,0)::real', 5/nullif(8,0)::real  as result union all 
select 'div_safe(5,8)', div_safe(5, 8)             as result union all

-- (string, int)
select 'div_safe(''5'',8)', div_safe('5', 8)       as result union all
select 'div_safe(''8'',5)', div_safe('8', 5)       as result union all

-- Rounding: Have to convert real result to numeric to pass it into ROUND (numeric, integer)
select 'round(div_safe(10,3)::numeric, 2)', 
        round(div_safe(10,3)::numeric, 2)           as result

+-----------------------------------+-------------------+
| ?column?                          | result            |
+-----------------------------------+-------------------+
| 5.1/nullif(null,0)                | NULL              |
| div_safe(5.1,0)                   | NULL              |
| 0/nullif(0,0)                     | NULL              |
| div_safe(0, 0)                    | NULL              |
| 5/nullif(8,0)::real               | 0.625             |
| div_safe(5,8)                     | 0.625             |
| div_safe('5',8)                   | 0.625             |
| div_safe('8',5)                   | 1.600000023841858 |
| round(div_safe(10,3)::numeric, 2) | 3.33              |
+-----------------------------------+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no problem with your usage. You could just as well use `anyelement` in this case, which would work with older releases.

Your function is good if you always want `real` as a result. If you want the result to have the same type as the arguments, use a pseudo-type for the result as well.